# Fancybox on close reload div

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to reload only a div and not the whole page if I close the Fancybox...
I've read many post for the same problem but anyone had a working solution for me.

Any Ideas ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Fancybox on afterClose function after your specified the Fancybox display parameters.

Your div:

```
 <div id="tree-image" class="tree-list-image"><a id="inline" href="PATH TO 
 YOUR 
 IMAGE" data-caption="YOUR IMAGE TITLE"><img src="PATH TO YOUR IMAGE" 
 alt="THIS IS AN IMAGE"/></a></div>
```

The Fancybox script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
/* This is basic - uses default settings */

$("a#inline").fancybox({
'opacity' : 0.4,
'autoSize' : true,      
'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
'speedIn'       :   100, 
'speedOut'      :   200, 
'overlayShow'   :   false,
'hideOnContentClick': true,
         afterClose : function( instance, current ) {
            $('#tree-image').load(document.URL +  ' #tree-image');

        }
});
});
</script>
```

You can also use -->

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

in the afterClose function.

I am honest when I say I do not understand why either or option always work. I always try the one then the other and on most occasions I get lucky. I guess it has something to do with the version of jQuery you are using.

Sometimes when I use fancybox to open a dialog, I use the same function to redirect to another page after fancybox is closed.

You can see a demo of the above on https://treeco.co.za/our-trees/

Answer (score 0):

in the `onClosed` event http://fancybox.net/api you can reload the div

```
$("#div").load("/url/to/reload");
```

or

```
 $("#div").html("refreshed content");
```

Comment: _I want to reload only a div and not the whole page_

Comment: Thank You, but how to implement this and where ?, I'm sorry but i'm new to fancybox... it have to look something around this : `$("#mydiv").html(" here comes something i didn't understand yet);`, right ?